# Is there a framework for running unit tests on Apache C modules?

Tags: c, unit-testing, apache, testing, cunit

I am about to make some changes to an existing Apache C module to fix some possible security flaws and general bad practices. However the functionality of the code must remain unchanged (except in cases where its fixing a bug). Standard regression testing stuff seems to be in order. I would like to know if anyone knows of a good way to run some regression unit tests againt the code. I'm thinking something along the lines of using [C-Unit](http://cunit.sourceforge.net.) but with all the tie ins to the Apache APR and status structures I was wondering if there is a good way to test this. Are there any pre-built frameworks that can be used with C-unit for example?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I've been thinking of answering this for a while, but figured someone else might come up with a better answer, because mine is rather unsatisfactory: no, I'm not aware of any such unit testing framework.

I think your best bet is to try and refactor your C module such that it's dependencies on the httpd code base are contained in a very thin glue layer. I wouldn't worry too much about dependencies on APR, that can easily be linked into your unit test code. It's things like using the request record that you should try to abstract out a little bit.

I'll go as far and suggest that such a refactoring is a good idea if the code is suspected to contain security flaws and bad practices. It's just usually a pretty big job.

What you might also consider is running integration tests rather than unit tests (ideally both), i.e. come up with a set of requests and expected responses from the server, and run a program to compare the actual to expected responses.

So, not the response you've been looking for, and you probably thought of something along this line yourself. But at least I can tell you from experience that if the module can't be replaced with something new for business reasons, then refactoring it for testability will likely pay off in the longer term.

Answer (score 1):

Spent some time looking around the interwebs for you as its a question i was curious myself. came across a wiki article stating that

http://cutest.sourceforge.net/

was used for the apache portable c runtime testing. might be worth checking that out.